# Name / Origin of Variable in Regression Formula

Tags: statistics, notation, correlation

I am writing a Maths Assignment for school in which I find a correlation between two sets of variables. The formula I am using for the gradient of the regression line is:

$$m=\dfrac{S_{XY}}{(S_X)^2}$$

Where

$$S_{XY}=\sum xy-\dfrac{\sum x\sum y}{n}$$
$$(S_X)^2=\sum x^2-\dfrac{(\sum x)^2}{n}$$

I am confused and cannot find any information online about the name or origin of the S variable. I need to include this into my report and it would be really helpful if anyone knows what it is!

Thank you :)

Comment: You have to add some more context, it is imppossible to decide what $S$ stands for without some more details.

Comment: $S_X$ is a usual notation for the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation), and $S_{XY}$ for the [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance). The formulas given here are a possible definition. The formula just above simply says that in the linear regression, the slope is given by $\dfrac{\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)}{\mathrm{var}(X)}$.

Comment: Thank you! I will give you credit for helping me. :)